# Admob stopped working

Tags: android, admob, ads

I have an android app working since february without any change, with an average 10USD per day. Two weeks ago, it now appears red ( inactive on the admob status).
My admob sdk is GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-4.3.1.jar (I've tried changing it to the latest version, same result), on adb logcat it appears as if no ad inventory exists.

I've filled the admob forms, two weeks ago, and no reply so far. How can I contact them? As this type of thing happened before? And why I haven't received any earning so far?

Answer (score 0):

The same happened to me. They will not answer nor notificate anything to you. Contacting them is harder than contacting the president. The most common reason is that you are violating the terms of use in some way, like giving incentives to the users to click the ads, or clicking the ads yourself several times...
Take a close look to your app, and create a new key in AdMob.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, "create a new key in AdMob." for that, I need to create another app, or can I delete or regenerate the current one?

Comment: you have to delete and create a new one...sorry

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your app has disabled due a violation
Check your mail
This happened to my after about three month they disabled it .. But I filled a form for re enable it .. And after a little time it back to work again

Comment: What form did you fill out?